# operand'*' cannot be applied to flota. float[]

Tags: java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_processing);
    /* getting the necessary information from the other activity for the necessary calculation. i m making a splitbill calculator */
    num1 =getIntent().getExtras().getInt("num1");
    num2 =getIntent().getExtras().getInt("num2");
    names = new String[num1];
    itemnames = new String[num2];
    checks= new Boolean[num1][num2];
    itemnames =getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("itemnames");
    names =getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("names");
    amt =getIntent().getExtras().getFloatArray("amt");
    qty =getIntent().getExtras().getFloatArray("qty");
    Boolean[][] objectArray = (Boolean[][])  getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("checks");
    for(int i=0;i<num1;i++){
        for (int k=0;k<num2;k++){
            checks[i][k]= (boolean)objectArray[i][k];
        }

    }
    prices= new float[num1];
    discount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.discount);
    tax = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tax);
    Button output = (Button)findViewById(R.id.output);
    output.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            disc = Float.parseFloat(discount.getText().toString());
            tx = Float.parseFloat(tax.getText().toString());
            for(int i=0;i<num2;i++){
                for (int k=0;k<num1;k++){
                    if(checks[k][i])
                    {
                        prices[k]+=amt[i]*qty*(disc/100);//i get an error here 
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

I want to know why i m getting this error, when i try to multiply the amount ie amt with

```
quantity(qty)
```

and discount, it says:

> operand '*' cannot be applied to float and float[]

Comment: Seems like `qty` is an array : `qty =getIntent().getExtras().getFloatArray("qty");`

Comment: ohh wait i got it

Comment: @Cid OP's dp looks like / is the character Purvi from [this CID series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CID_(Indian_TV_series)) lol

Comment: yeah it is :) haha